# Handle YUM package installation deployment for target environments(dev/prod/systest) using ansible playbook

Tags: linux, deployment, ansible

Need to handle YUM package installation deployement process with different versions/packages, for target environments(dev/prod/systest) using ansible playbook.
NOTE: I have gone through groups_var and hosts_var concept but did not understand if multiple packages with different versions can handled for deployment in multiple environment based on input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you found out, this separation can be achieved by using `group_vars` and `host_vars`. These are loaded in relation to the path of inventory file.

Simple example tasks like below will install different versions in **dev** and **prod** environments as explained below.

Example `playbook1.yml`:

```yaml
- hosts: appservers

  tasks:
  - name: install app-a
    yum:
      name: 'app-a-{{ app_a_version }}'
  - name: install app-b
    yum:
      name: 'app-b-{{ app_b_version }}'
```

Consider the example directory structure separating each environment's inventory:

```
dev/hosts
prod/hosts
systest/hosts
```

Each inventory file will contain hosts/groups for that environment.

**Dev environment:**

Example `dev/hosts`:

```
[appservers]
appserver1.dev
appserver2.dev
```

Then we can have variables specific to this environments in `dev/group_vars/appservers.yml`:

```yaml
---
app_a_version: 1.1
app_b_version: 5.5
```

Will install `app-a-1.1` and `app-b-5.5` when run as:

```
ansible-playbook playbook1.yml -i dev/hosts
```

**Prod environment:**

Example `prod/hosts`:

```
[appservers]
appserver1.prod
appserver2.prod
```

And variables defined in `prod/group_vars/appservers.yml`:

```yaml
app_a_version: 1.0
app_b_version: 5.0
```

But in prod it will install `app-a-1.0` and `app-b-5.0` when run as:

```
ansible-playbook playbook1.yml -i prod/hosts
```

`host_vars` work in similar way, and can be used to provide variables specific to each host of the inventory rather than groups in inventory.

Comment: thanks for your comment, issue is those package versions change dynamically in separate file which gets generated through a python script, and ansible playbook has to detect the changes, is there a way doing that?

Comment: If Python script generates file in YAML format, you can directly load them as [variable files](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_vars_module.html) with `include_vars:`. Or you could write some tasks (playbook) to read the files generated by Python script and write them into `group_vars`.